# Как получить id последнего сообщения Pyrogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyrogram

Требуется получить id последнего сообщения из избранного, данный вопрос уже задавал в теме [Pyrogram - получение id последнего сообщения из избранного](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1411751/pyrogram-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-id-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be) но ответа не получил

Answer (score 0):

можно так, но это будет реагировать на ВСЕ сообщения от ВАС

```
# импортируем нужные функции из pyrogram
from pyrogram import filters, Client
# создаем "клиента"
app = Client("my_account", api_id="ваш api_id", api_hash="ваш api_hash")
# подключаем функцию к клиенту и устанивливаем "фильтр" на нас
@app.on_message(filters.me)  
def main(_, msg):
    # получаем id (прибавляем 1 потому что id получаем на 1 меньше, 
    # по крайне мере так везде пишут XD для получения id)

    id = msg.message_id + 1
    print(id)  # пишем id

app.run()  # запускаем клиента
```